# Is there a remove page method corresponding to NewPageAsync() in PuppeteerSharp?

Tags: c#, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I keep the browser object as a singleton and would like to call NewPageAsync() for potentially thousands of urls. Is there a way to cleanup the page after it is used?

Comment: What do you mean with cleanup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can close the page using [CloseAsync](https://www.puppeteersharp.com/api/PuppeteerSharp.Page.html#PuppeteerSharp_Page_CloseAsync_PuppeteerSharp_PageCloseOptions_):

```cs
var page = browser.NewPageAsync();
////
await page.CloseAsync();
```

An `using` block will also close the page:

```cs
using (var page = await new browser.PageAsync())
{
///
}
```

Puppeteer-Sharp v2.0.3+ also supports `await using` blocks

```cs
await using (var page = await new browser.PageAsync())
{
 ///
}
```